# Не выдается результат работы скрипта

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь написать скрипт в пайтоне, который собирает со страницы тура и выдает ссылки на футбольные матчи:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_match_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    match_links = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('.fest .link')]


def main():
    url = 'http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/0/spieltag.html'
    match_links = get_match_links(get_html(url))
    return match_links

    print(match_links)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Когда пытаюсь запустить, то никаких ошибок не выдает, Sublime Text просто показывает >>>.

В терминале строка `match_links = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.select('.fest .link')]` работает как надо, выдает нужные мне ссылки списком. А вот вывести их в РЕПЛ не получается.

Comment: Вы сначала возвращаете, а потом принтите, но после `return` функция прекращает работу и до принта не доходит. уберите `return`,  и оставьте принт, или уберите принт и напишите `print(main())`

Comment: Alban, спасибо Вам. После первого предложенного Вами варианта в выдаче появилось None, а после второго вообще тишина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если стоит цель собрать только ссылки на матчи из таблицы, то сделать это можно вот так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


def get_match_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    match_links = [tag.get('href') for tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='link')]
    return match_links

def main():
    url = 'http://www.kicker.de/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/0/spieltag.html'
    match_links = get_match_links(get_html(url))
    return match_links

if __name__ == '__main__':
    links=main()
    print(links)
```

аутпут:

```
['/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317254/spielanalyse_1-fc-kaiserslautern-37_hannover-96-58.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317256/spielanalyse_vfl-bochum-8_1-fc-union-berlin-62.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317261/spielanalyse_sv-sandhausen-1604_fortuna-duesseldorf-13.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317262/spielanalyse_dynamo-dresden-65_1-fc-nuernberg-81.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317258/spielanalyse_spvgg-greuther-fuerth-82_1860-muenchen-5.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317257/spielanalyse_eintracht-braunschweig-41_wuerzburger-kickers-7283.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317259/spielanalyse_1-fc-heidenheim-11306_erzgebirge-aue-64.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317260/spielanalyse_arminia-bielefeld-10_karlsruher-sc-6.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/spieltag/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1/3317255/spielanalyse_vfb-stuttgart-11_fc-st-pauli-18.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/hannover-96-58/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/vfl-bochum-8/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/eintracht-braunschweig-41/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/vfb-stuttgart-11/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/spvgg-greuther-fuerth-82/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1-fc-heidenheim-11306/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/fortuna-duesseldorf-13/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/sv-sandhausen-1604/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/dynamo-dresden-65/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1-fc-nuernberg-81/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/arminia-bielefeld-10/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/karlsruher-sc-6/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1-fc-union-berlin-62/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/fc-st-pauli-18/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/wuerzburger-kickers-7283/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/erzgebirge-aue-64/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1860-muenchen-5/vereinsinformationen.html', '/news/fussball/2bundesliga/vereine/2-bundesliga/2016-17/1-fc-kaiserslautern-37/vereinsinformationen.html']
```

Comment: Кст, вместо `soup.find_all('a', class_='link')` можно было написать `soup.select('a.link')`

Comment: мне привычнее find_all() =)

Comment: Ну, `select` -- это css-селектор и он не только в bs используется, да и запись короче выходит, а писать вместо атрибута `class`, `class_` из-за того что это ключевое слово просто воротит :)

Comment: я ничего против css-селекторов не имею, можно и так, конечно. По поводу `class_` - меня воротило первые несколько раз, сейчас уже пообвыкся=)